# Multi-Thread PowerShell script to extract data faster from large XML file

Tags: powershell

The below script works as expected to get the desired output, but it takes a long  time to process large XML files (2GB and above). Calling on experts for suggestions on how to make it faster by multi threading or using some other technique in powershell script.

Reference Post -  to know more about the logic of below script: 
[Parse XML to extract data with grouping in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339705/parse-xml-to-extract-data-with-grouping-in-powershell/61340653?noredirect=1#comment108545075_61340653)

```
# Create XML object to load data into
$xml = New-Object -TypeName System.Xml.XmlDocument

# Load in XML file
$xml.Load("test.xml")

# Group XML child nodes by Priority
$groups = $xml.'ABC-FOF-PROCESS'.ChildNodes | Group-Object -Property PRIORITY

# Iterate groups and create PSCustomObject for each grouping
& {
    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            PRIORITY = [int]$group.Name
            KEY = ($group.Group.KEY | Select-Object -Unique).Count
            HITS = $group.Count
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object -Property PRIORITY -Descending | Out-File -FilePath output.txt
# Pipe output here
```

**Output:**

```
PRIORITY KEY HITS
-------- --- ----
       1   1    1
      -3   2    2
     -14   2    3
```

**xml:**

```
<ABC-FOF-PROCESS>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-14</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>F637A146-3437AB82-BA659D4A-17AC7FBF</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-14</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>F637A146-3437AB82-BA659D4A-17AC7FBF</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-3</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>D6306210-CF424F11-8E2D3496-E6CE1CA7</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>1</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>D6306210-CF424F11-8E2D3496-E6CE1CA7</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-3</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>4EFR02B4-ADFDAF12-3C123II2-ADAFADFD</KEY>
</H>
<H>
 <PRIORITY>-14</PRIORITY>
 <KEY>5D2702B2-ECE8F1FB-3CEC3229-5FE4C4BC</KEY>
</H>
</ABC-FOF-PROCESS>
```

Comment: How long does it take now? What kind of time would be acceptable?

Comment: It takes around 9 hrs to process 3 GB file using this script ,  main objective of solving this problem is to find out the statistics using the script in a short time most likely within 15 mins, rather than loading the XML into DB and then using sql to find statistics (takes around 12 hrs to load the file into DB).

Comment: Convert the whole XML as a CSV with columns for priority and key. Load into a database and do summing in SQL. Don't use XML data type within database, it's seldom efficient.

Comment: @vonPryz I do not want to load millions of records into DB to get this stat, instead I need to get the stats on the fly, thus DB housekeeping will be reduced. Since this script is not finalized yet, till now we are loading up the XML to DB, but unfortunately we can't convert XML to CSV due to software restrictions we have in place for this solution - which would be more efficient as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your xml is a fixed format, you could read the file line by line and adjust the results as you go.

It's not parallel, it's not as robust as using the xml parsing capabilities and it will not win any beauty awards but it should be pretty fast.

```
$hits = @{} # Hashtable containing number of hits per priority
$keys = @{} # Hashtable containing unique keys per priority
switch -Regex -File $env:temp\test.xml
{
    '^\s+<PRIORITY>(?<priority>[-]?\d+)'
    {
        $currentPriority = $matches.Priority
        $hits[$currentPriority] = $hits[$currentPriority]+1
        continue
    }
    '^\s+<KEY>(?<key>[\w-]+)'
    {
        $currentKey = $matches.Key
        if ($keys[$currentPriority] -eq $null) {$keys[$currentPriority] = @{}}
        $keys[$currentPriority][$currentKey] = $null
    }
}

$hits.GetEnumerator() | % {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PRIORITY = [int]$_.Key
        KEY = $keys[$_.Key].Count
        HITS = [int]$_.Value
    }
} | Sort PRIORITY -Descending
```

**Tested on a 500MB xml**

```
PRIORITY KEY    HITS
-------- ---    ----
       1   1 1000000
      -3   2 2000000
     -14   2 3000000

$timer

IsRunning Elapsed          ElapsedMilliseconds ElapsedTicks
--------- -------          ------------------- ------------
    False 00:02:25.7186698              145718    413249113
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would test this shortly and I shall share my feedback.

Comment: I was able to get the script up and running with a little tweak in the code. The script you've shared was helpful in solving unprecedented issues where the input XML had control characters like STX.etc , as the solution was based out of regex it was beneficial. And again the script was pretty fast in getting the job done.

Comment: Earlier, I had to stick to a backup plan to rely on python script as it was traditionally known to be a efficient ,  but in my case - your script worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Tested with a large XML file (2.4 GB) and it gets completed by 16 mins which is amazing.

Comment: @Naga - Thanks for the feedback. Can you share what the issue was so I can improve the answer?

Comment: one of my keytest case which is focused on logic of the script was failing -  details of the test case is updated in my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339705/parse-xml-to-extract-data-with-grouping-in-powershell/61340653?noredirect=1#comment108545075_61340653. To solve this I pushed KEY and priority to a hash-table, then again KEY and hits to another hash-table and i had loop thru both the tables to group and get the maximum priority and sum of the hits.

Comment: looping thru hastables indeed took a toll on performance - after finalizing the logic now the time to complete the script is around 35 mins for 2.4 GB file, if you help on improving my logic that would be great.

Comment: is it possible to write and append output to a .txt in when the script is in-progress?

Comment: Yes but that would get pretty convulated

Answer (score 1):

I guess this one of the examples where the focus has been on a single command ([Runtime of Foreach-Object vs Foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636701/1701026)) rather then to complete solution.

In general, I would recommend you to look at your whole solution and not just to a single statements as [the performance of a complete (PowerShell) solution is supposed to be better than the sum of its parts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437162/1701026).

In your case, if you need to instantiate a script and invoke that with the [Call Operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#call-operator-) just because you want to use the `Foreach` statement, you probably aim beyond goal:

For the small file you supplied,
This (using the pipeline with the `ForEach-Object`):

```
$groups | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        PRIORITY = [int]$_.Name
        KEY = ($_.Group.KEY | Select-Object -Unique).Count
        HITS = $_.Count
    }
} | Sort-Object -Property PRIORITY -Descending # | Out-File -FilePath output.txt
```

Appears generally faster then this (using the `ForEach` Statement and a the Call Operator):

```
& {
    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            PRIORITY = [int]$group.Name
            KEY = ($group.Group.KEY | Select-Object -Unique).Count
            HITS = $group.Count
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object -Property PRIORITY -Descending | Out-File -FilePath output.txt
```

Due to the nature of the `Sort-Object` cmdlet (all objects are required to be able to sort it) it will need to stall the pipeline to reorder them, for the same reason, a multi threading approach will probably not make much sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would test this shortly and I shall share my feedback.